# Program to set up a binary tree, print it & search - Node Class C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, binary-tree, nodes

I have created a program which contains a class Node, for representing a binary tree of any type(template).

In my Node.h class, I have two constructors, however I am not sure if I implemented both of them correctly. Initialising the values within the constructors has confused me. In my main.cpp file, I have a setUpTree function. My program executes now, but doesnt print the tree that is set up.

I have tried for hours trying to fix this but to no ends. I am not really experienced with C++, pointers, constructors etc yet.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me fix my code so that the setUpTree function works, and also the printTree method.

Thanks

Node.h Class:

```
   #ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//an object of type node holds 3 things
// - an item (of type t)
// - a left subtree
// - a right subtree

template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    Node(T item); //constructor to create a leaf node
    Node(T item, Node *lft, Node *rht); //constructor which creates an internal node 
    ~Node(); //Destructor

    //public data member functions:
    bool searchTree(T key);
    void printTree();

private:
    //private data member functions:
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    T item;
};

//constructor 
template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T i, Node<T> *lft, Node<T> *rht) {
    item = i;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}

//constructor 
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T i) { //should i be a parameter here?
    item = i; //is this right for this constructor?
}

//destructor
template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
    //delete;
}


//print tree method
template <typename T>
void Node<T>::printTree() {
    if (left != NULL) {
        left->printTree();
        cout << item << endl;//alphabetical order
    }

    if (right != NULL) {
        right->printTree();
        //cout << item << endl; //post order
    }
}

//search Tree method
template <typename T>
bool Node<T>::searchTree(T key) {
    bool found = false;
    if (item == key) {
        return true;
    }
    if (left != NULL) {
        found = left->searchTree(key);
        if (found) return true;
    }
    if (right != NULL) {
        return right->searchTree(key);
    }
    return false; //if left and right are both null & key is not the search item, then not found == not in the tree.
}

#endif
```

Main.cpp Class:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//set up tree method
Node<string> *setUpTree() {
    Node<string> *s_tree =
        new Node<string>("Sunday",
        new Node<string>("monday",
        new Node<string>("Friday"),
        new Node<string>("Saturday")),
        new Node<string>("Tuesday",
        new Node<string>("Thursday"),
        new Node<string>("Wednesday")));
    return s_tree;
}

int main() {

    Node<string> *s_tree;
    s_tree = setUpTree(); //call setUpTree method on s_tree

    cout << "Part 2 :Printing tree values: " << endl;
    s_tree->printTree(); //call print tree method

    cout << endl;

    //search for range of tree values
    //searchTree(s_tree, "Sunday");
    //searchTree(s_tree, "Monday");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the only problem but... if you construct a leaf, you have to set `left` and `right` pointers to `NULL`

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T i) : left(NULL), right(NULL), item(i)
 { }
```

otherwise, when the destructor is called

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
    //delete;
}
```

`delete` is called over undefined values; two times.

It's a perfect recipe for a crash.

Other problems in every point you use `left` or `right` checking if the pointer is `NULL`, as made in `printTree()` or `searchTree()`: the value is undefined, so can be non `NULL`, pass the test and `printTree()` is called over a pointer with an undefined value

**-- EDIT --**

Suggested contructors.

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node (T i, Node<T> * lft, Node<T> * rht)
 : left(lft), right(right), item(i)
 { }

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node (T i)
 : left(NULL), right(NULL), item(i)
 { }
```

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

> it is now printing some values at least ; monday sunday tuesday. not sure about the rest

Look at your `printTree()` metod

template 
void Node::printTree() {
    if (left != NULL) {
        left->printTree();
        cout << item << endl;//alphabetical order
    }

```
if (right != NULL) {
    right->printTree();
    //cout << item << endl; //post order
}
```

}

It print the value (`item`) **only** if `left` isn't `NULL`. So it doesn't print the value of the leafs.

Suggestion: modify `printTree()` to print `item` even when `left` is `NULL`.

By example

```
template <typename T>
void Node<T>::printTree() {
    if (left != NULL) {
        left->printTree();
    }

    cout << item << endl;

    if (right != NULL) {
        right->printTree();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code, so the constructor, now sets them to NULL template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T i, Node<T> *lft, Node<T> *rht) {
    item = i;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}

is this what you mean?

Comment: @Liam - yes; I suggest to inzialize the values in the initialization list (sorry: forgetted a `:`; corrected now) but your correction should be enough.

Comment: program executes now without crashing but doesn't print any values

Comment: @Liam - sorry but I see it only now: you have changed the wrong constructor; the constructor that receive `lft` and `rht` was right; is in the constructor that receive *only* a `T` that you have to impose `left = right = NULL`.

Comment: so the second constructor that only receives T i : template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T i) { 
 item = i; 
 left = NULL;
 right = NULL;
} 
?

Comment: @Liam - yes: only the second (leaf case) contructor.

Comment: what do you mean? the first constructor shouldnt be setting them to NULL ,only the second constructor should?

Comment: @Liam - answer improved; I suggest you to delete your constructor and use the two suggested.

Comment: very good, it is now printing some values at least ; monday sunday tuesday. not sure about the rest.  what is the difference in these constructors?

Comment: @Liam - improved answer to print leaf nodes; about difference in constructor, search for "initialization list"; look, by example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) and first answer

Comment: it prints them alphabetically now after making that change to the printTree method. Thanks appreciate it.

Comment: when i un-comment one of the searchtree calls, it says error: identifier searchTree is undefined?

Comment: never mind, fixed it! had to put call it by s_tree->searchTree(key).

Answer (score 2):

First the return in `setupTree` should be `s_tree`.

Second you construct a binary tree by adding each item one at a time.  I would suggest making `setupTree` accept an array of values that you can then take one at a time and build the tree.

As was pointed out the default values for left and right should be NULL.  However, I would just do it in the declaration, so that you don't have to repeat it in every constructor where the values aren't specified:

```
private:
    //private data member functions:
    Node* left = NULL;
    Node* right = NULL;
    T item;
```

Comment: thanks, stupid mistake. are the constructors correct in my Node.h class? and also not sure what the brackets are all about in the setUpTree method the lecturer only showed the slides for a few secs so not too sure if they are correct

Comment: Other than ,as pointed out by `max66`, using NULL as default values for the sub nodes, they seem OK to me.

Comment: I think the lecturer was probably showing you how he/she wanted the data organized.  You have to re-write your code to take an array of values and iterate through them one at a time and add them to the tree.